# Real world array covariance problem

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, covariance, contravariance

I'm trying to create an array of the class DataTableColumn, but unfortunately I'm going crazy with that.
By now that's what I tried to do without any success

```
public interface IDataTableColumn<out TValue> {
    string Expression { get; }
    DataTableFilterType FilterType { get; }

    TValue Cast(string value);
}

public class DataTableColumn<TValue> : IDataTableColumn<TValue> {
    public DataTableColumn(string expression, DataTableFilterType filterType = DataTableFilterType.Equal) {
        Expression = expression;
        FilterType = filterType;
    }

    public string Expression { get; private set; }
    public DataTableFilterType FilterType { get; private set; }

    public TValue Cast(string value) {
        return value.As<TValue>();
    }
}
```

My array SHOULD be like

```
private readonly IDataTableColumn<object>[] _columns = {
    new DataTableColumn<int>("Id"), // ERROR
    new DataTableColumn<string>("Description", DataTableFilterType.StartsWith), // SUCCESS
    new DataTableColumn<DateTime?>("Date"), // ERROR
};
```

Actually working like that

```
private readonly dynamic[] _columns = {
    new DataTableColumn<int>("Id"),
    new DataTableColumn<string>("Description", DataTableFilterType.StartsWith),
    new DataTableColumn<DateTime?>("Date"),
};
```

I think that using dynamic isn't the best way to do that.. someone shed light, please!

**EDIT**

damn I forgot the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   DataTableColumn< int >' to
>   'IDataTableColumn< object >'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   DataTableColumn< System.DateTime? >' to
>   'IDataTableColumn< object >'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is because `int` and `DateTime` are value types which are not covariant with `object` (they require boxing). I receive the following error when I compile your code:

```
covar.cs(23,13): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type
    'DataTableColumn<System.DateTime>' to 'IDataTableColumn<object>'.
    An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

[Per MSDN, "Variance in Generic Interfaces (C# and Visual Basic)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx):

> Variance in generic interfaces is supported for reference types only. Value types do not support variance. For example, `IEnumerable<int>` (`IEnumerable(Of Integer)` in Visual Basic) cannot be implicitly converted to `IEnumerable<object>` (`IEnumerable(Of Object)` in Visual Basic), because integers are represented by a value type.

`DataTableColumn<string>` works because it derives directly from `object`.

Comment: But there's no way to do something like that? none approach?

Comment: @Kim, the answer is usually to have `IFoo<T>` derive from `IFoo`, and then let your array be of type `IFoo`. Covariance works for *reference types*, which is why you're seeing your error.

Comment: Ok Everyone, I'm just trying here to find the 'answer' for my problem, and not the cause for the problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kim: Well the answer is your strategy is not likely to be feasible. @Anthony's suggestion is a common approach.

Comment: I'll use the @Anthony's suggestion. Thanks for both of you.